# UDP Listener in C not outputting correct hex information

Tags: c, udp, qudpsocket

I am trying to listen on a specific port (6053) and I want to print all of the data that is coming across that port. But I can't seem to get my program to run correctly, it outputs faulty data / incorrect data, as it does not match the data coming out of wire shark. If anyone has any input or suggestions of a direction I should head, it would be much appreciated!

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <WinSock2.h>
    #include <winsock.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <assert.h>

int main(void) {
sockaddr_in si_me, si_other;
int s;
assert((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) );//!= -1
int port = 6053;
int broadcast = 1;

setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST,
    (const char * )&broadcast, sizeof broadcast);

memset(&si_me, 0, sizeof(si_me));
si_me.sin_family = AF_INET;
si_me.sin_port = htons(port);
si_me.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

assert(::bind(s, (sockaddr *)&si_me, sizeof(sockaddr)) );//!= -1

while (1)
{
    char buf[10000];
    int slen = sizeof(sockaddr);
    recvfrom(s, buf, sizeof(buf) - 1, 0, (sockaddr *)&si_other, &slen);

    printf("recv: %x\n", buf);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you do not check return result of the `recvfrom`, so your `buf` array may contain faulty data / incorrect data exactly as you described it. Could you check MSDN documentation, for instance (or any other recvfrom manual) as it contains a good starting point:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740120(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("recv: %x\n", buf);
```

expects `buf` to be an `int`, which it prints in hexadecimal notation. But `buf` is not an `int`; it's a `char*` (after decay). So you're lying to  `printf` about the type of `buf`, causing Undefined Behaviour. One possible expression of the UB would be that the hexadecimal value printed is the last 32 bits of the *address* of your buffer, which is certainly not going to have anything to do with the data received.

Had you compiled with `-Wall` your compiler would have warned you about that.

It might also have warned you about the fact that you are not using the return value of `recvfrom`. Since UDP transmissions might include NUL bytes (and therefore are not normally C strings, which cannot include NULs), you need to know how many bytes you received. `recvfrom` provides that information as its return value, which will also tell you whether there was an error or not. There is no other way to know how many bytes were received, so use of the return value is effectively mandatory.

Since the packet received by `recvfrom` will not be NUL-terminated, there is no point reserving a byte for the NUL termination; it won't be used. (If you knew for a fact that the packets were strings and you wanted the buffer to be NUL-terminated, you would have to do that yourself using the length returned by `recvfrom`. In that case, you would need to leave space for the byte.)